# how to access with mysql_select_db this kind of structure

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry this might sound like a stupid question, but do not even know how to look for a term on Google about this, this is the picture:

[a busy cat http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/5041/structure.png](http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/5041/structure.png)

I am trying to get to the database _users,

tried using the following:

```
mysql_select_db("_users");
mysql_select_db("thedrive_users");
mysql_select_db("thedrive");
```

None allowed me to perform a query on any of the tables that are inside _users, all warnings about it not being a valid resource for mysql.

The connection is good by the way, points as a resource and not false with

```
mysql_connect
```

Also I know I should move on to PDO but get very used to that kind of syntax.

I have never seen a subset like that in my life in phpmyadmin and that's the problem.
For example I can access information_schema without problems

Comment: Second one is correct.  The grouping is a cPanel thing, "thedrive" part is usually the username and the second part is the database name.  You did mention it but anyway, please don't use `mysql_*` functions for new projects.  They are deprecated and will be removed.  Use instead `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO`.

Comment: I will delete this question if it's considered out off topic because what happened is that the user had to be added first via cpanel for it to retrieve from the database. That was the issue, the user needed to be added through Cpanel.

Comment: I guess I was right, then. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Mysql connect. First, you have to connect the mysql databese. After you have already connected to the database you can get rows from database.

A simple example:
users table named users:
first row: id, second row: name third row: password

You can get them like this:

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users');

while ($i = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
print('id:'.$i["id"].' name:'.$i["name"]);
}
```

Do you get it? 
But there is a good tutorial: http://www.learnphpin24hours.org/

Comment: Your database name is thedrive, your user table is _user ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use

```
 $hostname = "localhost";
 $database = "thedrive_users";
 $username = "username";
 $password = "password";
 $Connect_db = mysql_pconnect($hostname, $username, $password) or             trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);



 mysql_select_db($database, $Connect_db);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to select the database with `mysql_select_db` just make sure you reference the database in the query:

```
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM thedrive_users.table_name');
```

If that doesn't work, you may not have permission to access the database with the login details that you provided.

And, yeah, the usual bit about not using `mysql_*` blah blah blah.